# jquery, add class if select box has no value

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can hide a select box (using `.hide()`) if it doesn't have a value?

I'm currently just doing this;

```
// Hide second select box by default
$( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).addClass( "hidden" );

// Show second select box once first box's value changes
$( "select#val_sidebar_nav_001" ).change( function() {
    $( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
} );
```

But once I save the page the second select box disappears again, so what I need to do is add this `.addClass( "hidden" );` ONLY when the select box has no value.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass` and trigger at least once the `change` event :

```
$( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).addClass( "hidden" );

// Show second select box once first box's value changes
$( "select#val_sidebar_nav_001" ).change( function() {
    $( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).toggleClass("hidden",!($(this).val()===""));
} ).change();
```

toggleClass will remove or add class depending of the first select box value. I Don't have your HTML so you might change a thing or 2.
You need to trigger the change event once to apply style with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var $select2 = $( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" );
if(! $select2.val()){
    $select2.addClass("hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your first select tag has an option that provides instructions e.g. "select a value", you can do something like this.

```
.hidden { display: none; }

<select id="select1">
    <option value="0">-Select A Value -</select>
    <option value="1">Value 1</select>
    <option value="2">Value 2</select>
    <option value="3">Value 3</select>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="hidden">
    <option value="1">Value 1</select>
    <option value="2">Value 2</select>
    <option value="3">Value 3</select>
</select>

$('#select1').change(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex > 0) {
        $('#select2').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#select2').addClass('hidden');    
        $('#select2')[0].selectedIndex = 0; // reset the 2nd select tag.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make one new css as show class

```
.show{
display:block}
```

and now change your code to

```
// Hide second select box by default
$( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).removeClass('show').addClass( "hidden" );

// Show second select box once first box's value changes
$( "select#val_sidebar_nav_001" ).change( function() {
    $( "#val_sidebar_nav_002" ).removeClass( "hidden" ).addClass( "show" );
} );
```